# How to Identify and print the inbound properties in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

Hi i am working with mule and i want to know how to access incoming message inbound properties.
I am trying to get Mule_Originating_Endpoint property but i am unable to print or set it in some variable.

## [message.inboundProperties.MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `logger` without any `message` to log all properties and payload type:

```
<logger level="ERROR" />
```

Or log the inbound properties map:

```
<logger level="ERROR" message="#[message.inboundProperties]" />
```

Should print out something similar to {MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT=endpoint.polling.1912630717}

You should be able to access that property via `#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT]`

Or

## [message.inboundProperties['MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT']]

and so on.

Comment: Yes i want to put a check like #[message.inboundProperties.'MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT'== 'endpoint.http.localhost.8081.mule'] , instead of that i want to match only for http how to do that see i put * in place of that #[message.inboundProperties.'MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT'== 'endpoint.http.*']

Comment: For that I would look at the MEL regex function: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: please let me know if possible because my intention was just to check one condition to identify the call originator in composite source whether it is from HTTP or JMS based on that condition check i will route to some other sub flow .......